# Web.api Get method to show only selected properties from entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, asp.net-web-api

Let's say I have 3 entities: Advert, User and UserRole. And in Web.Api project GetAllAdverts method.

```
public IEnumerable<Advert> GetAllAdverts()
    {
        return repository.GetAll<Advert>();

    }
```

When i enter url *../api/advert* I get JSON with all Adverts and data about adverts, but I get all data about user and user role too.

How can I get for example all advert data and only UserName form entity User ?

Is this done by creating DTOs ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DTO's is usually a good idea. It is more work, but it gives you full control and it abstracts out peculiarities of a specific data layer.

In your case, if you really *only* want `UserName` you even have to use a DTO, because it is impossible to partly load the `User` as navigation property from `Advert`.

If it does not matter that you see all properties of `User` except its navigation properties (like role), you may also consider to (temporarily) turn off lazy loading for the context in the repository and eager load `Advert.User` by using `Include`.